# How to use r.Do and r.Branch in gorethink?

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I'm looking for clear example of r.Do() and r.Branch() functions in gorethink.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink - in lieu of any code to help fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of Go RethinkDB driver is very active on Github and you may get quicker answer if asking over there.

Here is an example of `Do`.

```
    res, _ := r.DB("test").Table("table").Get("ID").Do(func(issue r.Term) r.Term {
        return issue.Merge(map[string]string{
            "new_field": "new_value",
        })
    }).Run(session)
    var b []interface{}
    a.All(&b)
    fmt.Println(b)
```

I think the most important thing is to ensure we declare correct type `Term`. I import RethinkDB driver as `r` so I used `r.Term`. Then inside `Do` function, you can use any command from Term: https://godoc.org/github.com/dancannon/gorethink#Term

An example of `Do` and `Branch` at same time:

```
    r.DB("test").Table("issues").Insert(map[string]interface{}{
        "id": 1111,
    }).Do(func(result r.Term) r.Term {
        return r.Branch(result.Field("inserted").Gt(0),
            r.DB("test").Table("log").Insert(map[string]interface{}{
                "time":   r.Now(),
                "result": "ok",
            }),
            r.DB("test").Table("log").Insert(map[string]interface{}{
                "time":   r.Now(),
                "result": "failed",
            }))
    }).Run(session)
```

Basically, inside `Do`, we have access to return value of previous funciton call of RethinkDB, and we can continue to call ReQL command on that return value as in a `Map` function.

Inside `Branch`, we pass 3 arguments, all are `Term` type in Go RethinkDB driver. You can also refer to the official example: https://godoc.org/github.com/dancannon/gorethink#Branch

It's bit hard to get familiar with Go driver because of the nature of language and cannot fit in same dynamic style of official driver(Ruby, Python, JS). It's even more confusing in Language that we cannot chain command.